# How to extract the words after match when they are in a new line?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text extracted from a PDF:

```
asssd
name lastname
John Smith
sdds
```

I want to extract the name and the last name (John Smith).
I created the following regex:    `Name Lastname\s+(.*)$`  which works when I test it to https://regex101.com/ but NOT in my software which is C# based and on http://regexstorm.net/tester.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Remove `$`. Also, make sure you use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Name+Lastname%5cs%2b%28.*%29&i=asssd%0d%0aname+lastname%0d%0aJohn+Smith%0d%0asdds&o=i)

Comment: You need to specify the `Multiline` flag so that `$` matches end-of-lines (otherwise it only matches end-of-text)

Comment: As a starting point `(?<=name lastname\r\n)(.*)` seems to be working in the .NET tester:

`'http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3Dname%20lastname%5Cr%5Cn%29%28.*%29&i=asssd%0D%0Aname%20lastname%0D%0AJohn%20Smith%0D%0Asdds`

Comment: (?<=name lastname\r\n)(.*) by SnowGroomer and Name Lastname\s+(.*)  by Wiktor Stribiżew seem to be working to the .NET tester and on my software. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have above works if you do the following.

Add a space after the last name
Set the options to Multiline
Set the options to Ignore case.

You can do that with:

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
```

Your regex expression is using Capital N and capital L.

Furthermore, the \s+ in the expression means it needs to find at least one space before your match group.  So you might want to remove that and trim the result or look for the end of line character if you know there is going to be a line return.

Expresso is a handly regex tool for building .Net friendly regex expressions.  Most of the time its the options that cause problems between platforms. 
http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: No need for `RegexOptions.Multiline` since `$` is redundant and must be removed from the pattern.